# Error when deploying kube-dns: No configuration has been provided

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

I have just installed a basic kubernetes cluster the manual way, to better understand the components, and to later automate this installation. I followed this guide: https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/centos/centos_manual_config/

The cluster is completely empty without addons after this. I've already deployed kubernetes-dashboard succesfully, however, when trying to deploy kube-dns, it fails with the log:

```
2017-01-11T15:09:35.982973000Z F0111 15:09:35.978104       1 server.go:55]
Failed to create a kubernetes client: 
invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided
```

I used the following yaml template for kube-dns without modification, only filling in the cluster IP:
https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/deploy-addons.html

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experimenting with kubedns arguments, I added `--kube-master-url=http://mykubemaster.mydomain:8080` to the yaml file, and suddenly it reported in green.

How did this solve it? Was the container not aware of the master for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to put numeric IP on "--kube-master-url=http://X.X.X.X:8080". It's on yaml file of RC (ReplicationController), just like:

```
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kubedns
    ...
        args:
        # command = "/kube-dns"
        - --domain=cluster.local
        - --dns-port=10053
        - --kube-master-url=http://192.168.99.100:8080
```